# How to add space to AutoCompleteTextView suggestion

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, searchview

I would like to add space when the user select text from the auto complete suggestions, so when he continue to type he will start from a new word.

I tried to do it using `TextWatcher` but I get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Any suggestions?

[image]

the text watcher I used is:

```
    private class AddSpaceTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

    boolean shouldAddSpace = false;

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (count - before > 1) // check that the new input is not from the keyboard
            shouldAddSpace = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (shouldAddSpace) {
            shouldAddSpace = false;
            mAutoCompleteTextView.setText(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (18 ... 18) ends beyond length 1
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1018)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:611)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:607)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
        at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:99)
        at android.widget.SearchView.setQuery(SearchView.java:1465)
        at android.widget.SearchView.onQueryRefine(SearchView.java:889)
        at android.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.onClick(SuggestionsAdapter.java:371)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19748)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: could you post the code and the stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: maybe you need to call append instead of setText

Comment: can you post your arrayAdapter code..

Comment: can you show the piece of code where you are selecting the suggestion

Comment: can post your code of the adatper class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For selecting multiple items, you can simply use `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` which is a subclass of `AutoCompleteTextView` specifically built for this purpose.

OR

If you just want to append a space at the end making only one item selectable than try this:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    String text = editable.toString();
    if (shouldAddSpace && text.length() > 0 && !text.endsWith(" ")) {
        editable.append(' ');
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Once the space is appended, you can simply call `mAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();` to bring up the drop down again with updated text.

Comment: It does,so I'll give you the bounty, but I would also like the the cursor will move to the end of the text (after the " ").

Comment: @Pinhassi see my updated answer for updating cursor, and let me know if that does not work, I haven't tested but it should work!

Comment: I added "setSelection" to move the cursor to the end, and its perfect.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would solve your problem, but `mAutoCompleteTextView.setText(" ");` would remove the text. So I would do this:

```
mAutoCompleteTextView.setText(mAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString() + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mAutoCompleteTextView.setText(" ");
```

This code sets the text view text to " " - What you want is the existing text plus the space.

```
mAutoCompleteTextView.setText(mAutoCompleteTextView.getText().append(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using "MultiAutoCompleteTextView" to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
  android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
  android:ems="10" >
```

In java file:

```
private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
```

List of strings :

```
   String[] countries = getResources().
   getStringArray(R.array.list_of_countries);
   ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter
   (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
   actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This example displays list of countries corresponding to user input. 
I hope this example will be of some assist to your work.